# database isn't connecting without internet connection

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I am facing this problem while using **Xampp** mysql database with **SailsJS**.my application is running locally and connection code is as follows:

```
someMysqlServer: {
adapter: 'sails-mysql',
host: "localhost",
user:"root",
port     : '3306',
database: 'school'
}
```

when i start Xamp control panel **without internet connection** it's working well even request to **http://localhost** is also connecting to phpmyadmin,but my sails console says

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
at afterwards (D:\SchoolProject\node_modules\sails-    mysql\lib\connections\spawn.js:72:13)
at D:\SchoolProject\node_modules\sails-mysql\lib\connections\spawn.js:40:7
at Handshake.onConnect (D:\SchoolProject\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:54:9)
at Handshake.Sequence.end (D:\SchoolProject\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
at Protocol.handleNetworkError (D:\SchoolProject\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:355:14)
at PoolConnection.Connection._handleNetworkError     (D:\SchoolProject\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:367:18)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at net.js:950:16
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

while same application works with internet connection.I Cant figure this out any idea please?????

Comment: is it a show-stopper or a warning do you think, as in, hey I wanted to check for updates. I don't care that it says Error, that could just be what the developer chose to wrote at 2am

Comment: as far as i can understand it is something about host but i changed it to process.env.HOSTNAME too but obviously no work....

Comment: ok so you have a local XAMMP setup that you believe should work all the way through because of what you are expecting of it offline, but the error is a show-stopper

Comment: Try to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`

Comment: awesome this just worked for by adding 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but couldn't understand why???because i thought both are same localhost and 127.0.0.1(loopback IP).n why this wasn't problematic before.

Answer (score 1):

Replace host: "localhost" by host: "127.0.0.1"
I think it will work.

Comment: This was the correct solution, posted by @ghaiklor in August so I don't know why you felt the need to post the same solution.